# Have to specify Assembly name for all class references

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, .net-4.0

VS 2010, .NET 4.0, VB, EF 4.4

I was having issues deploying my web application to the server... was getting the error "Could not load type " when I tried running it on the server. Googling around I also found that my Web App should not have an "App_Code" folder (copied over shared but of code from other corporate Web Sites). So I moved all the classes from App_Code to a folder off the root ("BLL" - also the namespace of our code library).

Now when I run the app in the VS IDE I'm getting the error "Configuration Error. Could not load type 'BLL.Roles'" coming from the load of the web.config. If I add the assembly name of the app to the front of the "BLL.Roles" > "appName.BLL.Roles" I get past this line and error out at the next reference to "BLL".

I've Cleane and Rebuilt my project.

Why are my classes not getting recognized as part of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong but i believe because you are using a Web Site and not a Web application you can only access classes that live in the App_Code Folder. If you are working with a Web Application you can access classes no matter what folder they live in.  In that case you might have to move your files to a new project that is under a Application format and not a Web Site format.  I would try to move your files to a Web Application project.

Comment: It is a Web Application, the App_Code folder was created manualy by mistake (by another programmer when first setting up the project) and has been removed.

Comment: Did it build/Compile with classes in that folder?

Comment: At first, but after removing the folder I moved the class files to a folder off the root of the project("BLL"). Also made sure they are all set to Build Action=Compile